# Flash cs5 form TLF is not receiving hebrew in some computers and do in others

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, tlf

i have a TLF in a form in one of my sites.

from a reason i can not trace, in some cases users report that they can not write in hebrew while they can in english.
 i know that others can as 
1. i get completed forms in hebrew to my mail.
2. i can write in hebrew in my computers (mac and pc with win xp).

the users report that in hebrew they cant write nothing as the TLF is not responding to their typing.

the problem is the same when i try to embed the fonts and when i try to use "use system fonts" with Arial font.

i have asked one of my users who have reported that issue to update his flash player but that didn't help.

i have tried to get the users OS and browser and could not find any consistency.

I will appreciate any help as i am stuck.

thanks 
shani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What WMODE do you use?

There are many known issues regarding dynamic fonts and "opaque" or "transparent" WMODE.

Try to search in the [Adobe Flash Player Bug and Issue Management System](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa).

Comment: thanks, it worked like a charm. it was on "transparent" for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try the embedded font format, DefineFont4 instead of the traditional flash embedded fonts.

**Couple of websites that could help:**

http://cameronyule.com/2009/02/embedded-fonts-and-the-text-layout-framework

http://blogs.adobe.com/tlf/2008/11/embedded-font-subsetting-using.html

Comment: Hi i have embedded the fonts but it didn't help for my problem. thanks anyway